# unable to play downloaded .ts video files

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, aes, http-live-streaming, m3u8

i have downloaded a ts video file from m3u8 index file with the help of this python script

```
import requests
import m3u8
url1 = "url of the m3u8 file"
r = requests.get(url1)
master_m3u8 = m3u8.loads(r.text)

preurl = "preurl of the m3u8 file "

url2 = preurl + master_m3u8.data["playlists"][2]["uri"]
r2 = requests.get(url2)
sub_m3u8_file = m3u8.loads(r2.text)


with open("philosophy_intro.ts","wb") as f:
    for segment in sub_m3u8_file.data["segments"]:
        url = preurl + segment["uri"]
        res = requests.get(url)
        f.write(res.content)
```

and this is what segments of the playlists look like
[playlists segments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCoDe.png)

video of the size 800mb  is being downloaded but it dosen't play in any media player in my computer also when i try to convert it  to mp4 with moviepy script

```
import moviepy.editor as moviepy
clip = moviepy.VideoFileClip("philosophy_intro.ts")
clip.write_videofile("philosophy_intro.mp4")
```

it says failed to read the duration of the video file,whats the problem

Comment: Maybe the video files are encrypted. Do the m3u8 files contain decryption key info (`EXT-X-KEY` or `EXT-X-SESSION-KEY` tag)?

Comment: @jmsn yes they look like this --->   #EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="k/timestamp",IV=0x496daa1c6914000e408c65cead91fc29